# how to detect availability of GUI

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, gui

For Linux: I have a text mode installation (bash) script and a graphical mode setup program (a Free Pascal binary). I'd like to run the graphical setup when a GUI is available.

How do I detect which setup to launch? Or should I try to always launch the graphical setup and detect that it fails to launch? If so, how to do that?

Comment: duplicated question http://superuser.com/questions/244189/bashrc-how-to-know-x-window-is-available-or-not

Comment: I guess $DISPLAY will be valid even with Wayland and beyond. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could start it the GUI version, and fall back to text installation if the error message is that it can't connect to display server. All this with proper stdin/stderr redirection of course to not scare the user.